# Fail Ant build in case of no command line parameters

Tags: ant

I am sending a file path as a parameter to ant at command line. I want the build to fail if parameter doesnot exist. What is the way to do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the if attribute on a target e.g. :

```
<project name="test" default="init">
    <target name="init" if="${path}">
        <!--This will only execute if ${path} is defined from the command line-->
    </target>
</project>
```

Second option : more verbose

```
<project name="test" default="init">
    <target name="init">
      <fail message="Path is not set! Exiting ant script!">
        <condition>
          <not>
           <isset property="${path}"/>
          </not>
        </condition>
      </fail>
    </target>
</project>
```